# How to use Nested React Router in sub child or child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am making an App where i have to maintain a record of cars by firebase fireStore but I am having a problem in routing a component i don't know how to do routing within sub-component. All my code is mentioned in the Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/inventory-forked-yhg20 The scenario i am using is as followed

1. The components are **App.js Home.js ShowCars.js Header.js Car.js** and **EditCar.js**
2. The **App.js** contains **Header.js Home.js** and **ShowCars.js**
   [image: App.js]
3. In **Header.js** it works like a navbar where i can route to **Home.js** and **ShowCars.js**
4. When Clicking **Show Car** on NavBar **http://localhost:3000/showcar** Link is Created and in **ShowCars.js** Data is being fetched from firebase server and Array of cars are rendered on Every map By using **cars.map()**
   [image: ShowCar.js]
5. In **car.map()** a **Car.js** component is used which render a table row on Every map
   [image: Table in ShowCar.js]
   [image: Car.js]
6. In **car.js** i used an **Edit Link** and i want that edit Link to render an **EditCar.js** component and route it to the new path like **http://localhost:3000/showcar/edit** or **http://localhost:3000/edit** any suitable path will be acceptable. This is the Point where i don't know how to render to new component using **react-router**

The Solution of the Problem I require is

1. Go to new Path When Clicking the **Edit Link** and **EditCar.js** should be render

OR

2. Pass **car** as props through *< EditCar car={car} />* in **car.map()** and Go to new Path When Clicking the **Edit Link** and **EditCar.js** should be render  mentioned in comments  (This Should be first priority, if it is not possible then first point will also acceptable)

   ```
       return (
        <div>
          ShowCars
         <hr />
         <table className="table">
           <thead className="thead-light ">
             <tr>
               <th scope="col">#</th>
               <th scope="col">Name</th>
               <th scope="col">Chasis-No</th>
               <th scope="col">Color</th>
               <th scope="col">Edit</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             {cars.map(({ id, car }, index) => (
               <>
                 <Car key={id} car={car} index={index} />
                 {/* 
                       <Route path="/Edit" >
                           <EditCar car={car}/>. 
                       </Route>         
                 */}
               </>
             ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     );
   }

   export default ShowCars;
   ```

The Link for the Code is : https://codesandbox.io/s/inventory-forked-yhg20 . Edit the Code in CodeSandBox will be helpfull. Ask me if my information is incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if a user visits `/edit` directly? Then `ShowCars` component is never rendered so there would be no `/edit` route.

So I'm not really sure about option 2. But you can do:

1. You can navigate to `/edit/<carId>`, there you have the car id and can render the right car.
2. If you don't want the id in your path, you can use save the car id to the state of `to` object. See [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object)
3. Save the car id in global context

**Edit:**

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inventory-forked-0gh90?file=/src/App.js)

I think in `Header.js` you should add a slash at the beginning of `"showcar"` path

Comment: Point 1 is not a problem for me will it take me to <EditCar /> component directly after clicking Edit Link? if yes can you change the code in the link ?